# Proof of an identity in a Lebesgue-Bochner space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ such that $\partial_t u \in L^2(0,T;(H^1(\Omega))^*)$ and define the following function
$$
f_\epsilon(s)=\begin{cases}s \;\; \text{if} \hspace{0.4cm} \vert s\vert \leq \epsilon,\\
\epsilon \;\; \text{if} \hspace{0.4cm}  s > \epsilon,\\
- \epsilon \;\; \text{if} \hspace{0.4cm}  s < -\epsilon
     \end{cases}
$$
Prove that $\partial_t f_\epsilon(u) \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)^*)$ and that the following identity holds
$$
\partial_tf_\epsilon(u)=\partial_tu\; \mathbf{1}_{\vert u \vert < \epsilon}
$$
I know that the above identity holds true if we replace $\partial_t$ with $\nabla,$ but I'm not able to prove it for $\partial_t.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the publication https://dx.doi.org/10.14712/1213-7243.2015.168 it is shown that the time derivative of the positive part $\max(u, 0)$ (defined in a pointwise way) may not belong to $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)^\star)$. Since your function is very similar (truncation at $\pm \epsilon$ instead of truncation at $0$), I believe that $\partial f_\epsilon(u) \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)^\star)$ can fail.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting publication. As I understand,  in the latter, we can adapt the proof so that $\partial_t f_\epsilon(u) \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)^*)$ is not true in general, nevertheless they prove that the identity $\int_{I}\left\langle u_{t}(s), u^{+}(s)\right\rangle_{V^{*}, V} \mathrm{~d} s=\frac{1}{2}\left\|u^{+}(T)\right\|_{H}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left\|u^{+}(0)\right\|_{H}^{2}$ holds,  where $I=(0,T)$ and  $V=H^1(\Omega)$ and $H=L^2(\Omega)$. I guess  that the identity can also hold if we replace the positive part with $f_\epsilon(u)$. Doesn't it ?

Comment: @JackTell: Yes, I would say so. The proof is quite simple and, if I don't miss something, it can be transferred to your situation.